# Get reference to/update element on parent window

Tags: javascript

I have a page that lists unfinished items that uses a table to display what stage the item is at the current moment.  When a particular item is clicked, it displays the item in a separate tab.  When an item is updated and submitted from child page, I want it to update the list on the parent window.

The non-working code generates "Function expected" error at the "window.opener" line:

```
function reloadParent() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'ReportServlet',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {formType: "reloadActions"
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        asynch: false,
        success: function (responseText) {
window.opener.document.getElementById('tbodyReportList').innerHTML(responseText);
        }, error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert("An error occurred.  Error:  " + status + ", " + error);
        }
    });
}
```

Could use a push in the right direction here.  Thanks.

Comment: Just a little thing: the shortened format of ***asynchronous*** in programming is `async`, not `asynch`...  But this isn't related to your question

Comment: @FZs Good catch, regardless of whether it was related to the question or not.  Thank you, fingers must have gotten ahead of my brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

innerHTML is not a function, it is a property.

Try to change the line

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('tbodyReportList').innerHTML(responseText);
```

into

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('tbodyReportList').innerHTML = responseText;
```

You can find more info here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp